# Proper divisor of order of $\mathbb{F}^*_q$ must divide element its in prime decomposition?

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

I'm puzzled by a step in a proof in Lidl & Niederreiter's *Finite Fields*.  For the record, it's the proof of Theorem 2.8, "For every finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}^*_q$ of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is cyclic."  I'm not looking for *a* proof of the theorem per se; there are other proofs of it that I understand.  I want to understand this one.

Let $b_i = a_i^{h/p_i^{r_i}}$, where $a_i$ is some element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ that is not a root of $x^{h/p_i}-1$, and $p_i^{r_i}$ is an element in the prime factor decomposition of the order of $\mathbb{F}^*_q$, which is $h=p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$.

Lidl & Niederreiter write:

> We claim that element $b=b_1 b_2 \cdots b_m$ has order $h$.  Suppose, on the contrary, that the order of $b$ is a proper divisor of $h$, and is therefore a divisor of at least one of the $m$ integers $h/p_i$ ....

I understand everything in the proof up until this point, and everything after it.  What I don't understand is why, if the order of $b$ were a proper divisor of $h$, it must be a divisor of one of the elements $p_i^{r_i}$.  Why couldn't the order of $b$ be, say, $p_1^2 p_3$, if for example $h=p_1^3 p_2 p_3^2$ ?  After all, $\mathbb{F}^*_q$ is not a field, and a subgroup wouldn't necessarily be a field, so there's no reason on that score that the order of $b$ subgroup must be a prime power.

I've been puzzling over this now for a couple of weeks.  I suspect that there's something obvious that I am just not seeing--some dots I haven't connected--or that I am just confused about something.  I've gone back a few pages through theorems, and gone back to the groups section of this book and other books.  I've looked at different proofs of the same theorem, but they don't include the $b_1 b_2 \cdots b_m$ construction--at least not explicitly, and I don't see how it's implicit.  I thought that the answer might lie in theorems about orders of cyclic subgroups [L&N 1.15(ii), 1.15(iii)], and that may still be the case, but I don't see why.

(I'd be happy to be pointed to a dupe question.  The same idea may appear in another question, but I have not found it yet.)

Comment: They didn't say that it's a divisor of one of the elements $p_i^{r_i}$. They say that it's a divisor of one of the elements $h/p_i$. That is, $h/p_i = p_1^{r_1}\cdots p_i^{r_i - 1}\cdots p_m^{r_m}$.

Comment: You're right @WhatsUp.  Thanks very much for pointing out that error.  I knew that--i.e. realized it at an earlier point in time--but had lost track of the distinction  A similar question remains, for me, I think, which is why I got confused, fwiw, but I should rethink it and edit the question or delete it.

Comment: Oh! I get it, @WhatsUp.  Dividing $h/p_i$ just means dividing something less than $h$, so to speak, i.e. with one $p_i$ missing from the product.  If $b$ *only* divided $h$ as a whole, and not some fraction of it, $b$ would be $h$, i.e. not a proper divisor.  Thanks!  I suppose I will have to delete the question, but will leave it up for a day so I might be able to convey my sincere thanks to you in this comment.  I've been going around in circles with that step for so long ....

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @Mars Instead of deleting this (good!) question, why don't you answer it yourself?

Comment: Well, OK, @Servaes.  Thanks.  If you think it's worth retaining and answering, I'll do that, as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen.  Done.

Answer (score 2):

At the suggestion of commenters, I'm answering my own question, with thanks to @WhatsUp.

As @WhatsUp noted in a comment, Lidl & Niederreiter did not suggest that if the order of $b$ is a proper divisor of $h$, it must be a divisor of one of the prime power factors $p_i^{r_i}$ of $h$.  What they said was that the order of $b$ would have to be a divisor of $h/p_i$ for some $i$.

On the assumption that ord($b$) is a *proper* divisor of $h$, considering each instance of $p_i$ in $p_i^{r_i}$ as a distinct factor of $h$, at least one such $p_i$ instance is not a factor of ord($b$): that is, ord($b$) is a product of fewer instances of primes than $h$.  Thus since $h = p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_m^{r_m}$,

$$h/p_i = p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_i^{r_i - 1} \cdots p_{m-1}^{r_{m-1}} p_m^{r_m}$$

is such a quantity, created by dividing out $p_i$ from $h$. The expansion of $h/p_i$ shows that Lidl & Niederreiter did not exclude the possibility that ord($b$) could be a divisor of multiple factors $p_j^t, p_k^u$, etc. of $h$; it might divide any combination of factors in $p_1^{r_1} p_2^{r_2} \cdots p_i^{r_i - 1} \cdots p_{m-1}^{r_{m-1}} p_m^{r_m}$, were it a proper divisor of $h$.

Comment: In the third paragraph you make a slightly inaccurate claim. Even if $m=ord(b)$ is a proper divisor of $h$ it is still possible that all the primes $p_i$ are factors of $m$. For example, if $h=p_1p_2^2$ and $m=p_1p_2$. *But, it does follow that not all the powers $p_i^{r_i}$ are factors of $m$.* If $m$ is a factor of $h$, then we know that $m=p_1^{\ell_1}\cdots p_m^{\ell_m}$ with $\ell_i\le r_i$ for all $i$. If $m$ is a *proper* factor of $h$, then we further know that $\ell_i<r_i$ for at least one index $i$. If we fix such an $i$, then $m$ is a factor of $h/p_i$ et cetera.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen.  That's much appreciated!  What I intended to convey is what you said, but my way of putting it was not clear.  I've edited the first half of that paragraph to try to clarify the intended meaning.  I'd be interested in whether you think it's OK.  I admit that the "instance of a prime" language is, strictly speaking, a bit awkward, since every $p_i$ in $p_i^{r_i}$ is the same.  (There's only one instance of any prime number; perhaps only Platonists would agree.)  The way you put it is precisely correct.  I'm trying to make the point as easy to understand as possible.

Comment: As long as your understood the problem I pointed out, it's fine :-). Communicating that more clearly comes with practice (and is one of the skills of the trade).

Comment: Yes, I understood @JyrkiLahtonen.  Thank you.